# Setting Model id With id Property

Tags: backbone.js, model, attributes

http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#Model-id indicates that the `id` property of a `model` is special because if `my_model.set("id", <new_id>)` is called, `my_model.id` will have that new value.  This property is not commutative, however.  Calling `my_model.id = 4` followed by `my_model.get("id")` will not result in 4.

Is there a way to have `my_model.id=4` set the value of `my_model.attributes.id` so that `my_model.get("id")` will result in 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieves what you want like this :

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.get = function(attr) {
    if (attr == 'id' && this.attributes[attr] != this.id) {
        this.attributes[attr] = this.id;
    }
    return this.attributes[attr];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want, you can override the get method of Backbone.Model, but that is not a very good proposition cause there is a reason why model id and id property of attribute are separated from each other, id of model is something local to backbone and id property of the attribute is something that might be used by the remote servers when you sync your model.

So in usual cases, overriding the get function of Model can cause trouble in future.